# Wifi disconnects and reconnects on its own frequently on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

Tags: networking, iwlwifi

I am using Ubuntu20.04 LTS for sometimes by dual boot on my Dell Inspiron 5559 and I use TP-Link router. I use wifi without any problem in my Windows 10 os. But on Ubuntu the connection disconnects on its own and it is very frequent. It also connects on its own after 20-30 seconds.

► The output of lspci -knn | grep Net -A3 command

```
01:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wireless 3160 [8086:08b3] (rev 83)
Subsystem: Intel Corporation Dual Band Wireless AC 3160 [8086:8470]
Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
Kernel modules: iwlwifi
```

► The output of sudo journalctl  -b 0 -u NetworkManager command.
There were 100 lines of output and had three warnings. Only the warnings are included here.

```
Nov 23 10:39:49 fuad NetworkManager[812]: <warn>  [1606106389.7636] sup-iface[0x55e132739120,wlp1s0]: connection disconnected (>
Nov 23 10:38:14 fuad NetworkManager[812]: <warn>  [1606106294.5262] sup-iface: failed to cancel p2p connect: P2P cancel failed
Nov 23 10:38:13 fuad NetworkManager[812]: <warn>  [1606106293.8612] Error: failed to open /run/network/ifstate
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3` terminal command.

Comment: Look at the logs!  `sudo journalctl  -b 0 -u NetworkManager`.

Answer (score 1):

For this Intel 3160 adapter I would suggest running

```
sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi-opt.conf <<< "options iwlwifi 11n_disable=8"
```

and reboot.

You can revert this setting by

```
sudo rm /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi-opt.conf
```

Comment: I ran the code above. But this problem is still happening. I noticed that when the internet is slow or more people are added to the network it happens more frequently but does not on windows.